# What to enqueue if there's a new blossom when using the blossom algorithm for weighted matching

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

I'm reading [Galil's paper on "Efficient Algorithms for Finding Maximum Matching in Graphs"](https://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edragan/GraphAn/p23-galil.pdf).

**Background**

For finding the maximum cardinality matching in general (non-bipartite) graphs (section 4), Galil defines a blossom to be a particular cycle: an odd-length alternating path from [an S-vertex] to itself". Then he

- writes about Edmonds' idea of shrinking a blossom (before Theorem 2) by considering the blossom to be a super-vertex and
- introduces Q as a queue "where new S-vertices are inserted".

Towards the end of the page, Galil writes "[w]hen a new blossom is generated...its subblossoms that are still in Q are deleted from Q."

The above makes sense to me.

**Question**

For finding the maximum *weighted* matching in general graphs (section 7), he writes "[w]hen, during the search [for an augmenting path], a new blossom is formed, the vertices in its T-blossoms become S-vertices and are inserted in the queue Q."

But vertices in those T-blossoms were shrunk (when the T-blossoms were created). (And the new blossom shrinks the T-blossoms themselves.) So what is the intuition for enqueuing already-shrunk vertices (and ensuring they are labelled S)?